# HOW fix calculate the total of two decimal error

Tags: javascript, calculator, calculated-columns

This function is calculate the total of debit number by the dynamic table, the problem is, it counted `2.6 + 2.1 = 4.00`,  I want the answer to be `4.70`, but it didn't count on two decimal.

```
function debitvalues() {
    var debittotal = 0;
    var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].name == "debit[]") {
            if (obj[i].value > 0) {
                debittotal += parseInt(obj[i].value * 1);
            } else {
                obj[i].value = 0;
                debittotal += parseInt(obj[i].value * 1);
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("debittotal").value = (debittotal * 1).toFixed(2);
    debittotal = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You parse to `int` while you need to parse to `float`:

```
parseInt(obj[i].value*1)
```

`parseInt` => `parseFloat`

`parseInt` gives you a natural number-**N** while `parseFloat` gives you a real number-**R**.

BTW, when you multiple a number-**x** by one you get the very same x number so I think your calculator can skip it...

```
parseInt(obj[i].value*1) => parseFloat(obj[i].value)
```